# What is the radius parameter in text_add()?

Tags: python, text-object

I'm using Blender 2.79. The Python function bpy.ops.object.text_add() has an optional parameter named radius, which doesn't seem to have been there in older versions.
I tried values between 0 and 40000 and the text object generated looks the same.
The documentation is not very helpful - the description for this parameter is "Radius".
Does anybody know what this parameter is intended to do, and if it works at all at this time? (I was secretely hoping that it would align the text along a circle with the specified radius, but so far I can't get it to do anything.)

Comment: Ensure you use a float type number. If working correctly it will set the font size.

Comment: That's correct, it works properly now. Thank you for the clarification.